# Get Disk info and Convert to GB

Tags: powershell

I have been working on this script to capture disk sizes, however I have them in bytes and they're messy, I have looked at several ways to add a decimal point, but I'm having trouble converting to GB first, Also alongside disk sizes I am trying to calculate free disk size and percentage used.

```
$servers = (Get-AdComputer -Filter "name -like MY-VM-*'").Name | Sort-Object

foreach ($Server in $Servers)
{
$disks= get-wmiobject -ComputerName $Server Win32_volume | select-object pscomputername, Capacity, driveletter, freespace |`
 format-table | out-file c:\temp\new3.txt -append

Foreach ($disk in $disks)
{
  $driveletter = $disk.driveletter
  $totalsize = $disk.capacity
  $freespace = $disk.freespace
  $freespace = [math]::round($freespace[$_] /9.3132257461548)
  $Percent_Free = [math]::round(($freespace / $totalsize ) * 100)
   }  
}
```

Hope that makes sense :)

Comment: `1073741824 / 1gb` -> `1`. PowerShell has this conversion built-in, no need for you to do inscrutable divisions with magic constants.

Answer (score 1):

Your query has already been answered in the comment. You can directly do this -

```
$servers = (Get-AdComputer -Filter "name -like MY-VM-*'").Name | Sort-Object

foreach ($Server in $Servers)
{
$disks= get-wmiobject -ComputerName $Server Win32_volume | select-object pscomputername, Capacity, driveletter, freespace |`
 format-table | out-file c:\temp\new3.txt -append

Foreach ($disk in $disks)
{
  $driveletter = $disk.driveletter
  $totalsize = $disk.capacity/1GB
  $freespace = $disk.freespace/1GB
  $Percent_Free = [math]::round(($freespace / $totalsize ) * 100)
   }  
}
```

Comment: Hi Thanks for the quick response, but I get this result, in bytes..PSComputerName     Capacity driveletter    freespace
--------------     -------- -----------    ---------
My-VM-01           366997504                331563008
My-VM-02           75159826432 D:           74651119616
My-VM-03           49213440 E:              36892672

Comment: That's because the output file `new3.txt` is generated before the conversion in `GB`. Simply pipe the `Out-File` cmdlet to `foreach` loop, and you will get your expected result.

Comment: thanks Vivek that makes perfect sense, just a couple of quick questions, where do I put the out-file pipe command .. also I now get $percent_free=[math]::(($freespace /$totalsize) * 100) error saying attempted to divide by zero 

Comment: Do you have any `Compact Disk` in your `VM`?
In my experience, they will usually cause `divide by zero` exception. You can filter add `DriveType` filter to your `$disks` and eliminate `DriveType = 5`(which enumerates to Compact Disk).

And you can enclose your script block within `@( YourScriptBlock ) | Out-File SomeFileName.txt -append`

Comment: thanks Vivek can we continue this on email chat, my email is Rajinder.rahul@gmail.com 

Comment: Using this but can't get percentage to work .. `$Computers = (Get-AdComputer -Filter "name -like 'My-VM-*'").Name | Sort-Object 
gwmi Win32_volume -Computer $Computers -Filter 'DriveType = 3' `
  | select pscomputername, driveletter,
           @{n='FreeSpace';e={[int]($_.FreeSpace/1GB)}},
           @{n='Capacity';e={[int]($_.capacity/1GB)}} | format-table | Out-File c:\temp\disk.txt -Append`